# Highcharts - Get and plot data with MySQLi + JSON (step by step)

Tags: javascript, php, json, mysqli, highcharts

I'm tryng to plot a simple series into a pie chart; my data come from an SQL database, and I want to keep the Mysqli query in a separate file (in order to dinamically change my data series if I need). I'll try to describe you step-by-step what I'm doing, asking you to correct me if I'm doing something wrong (I'm a total newbie in Highcharts and javascript...).

1) `MySqli` query and `json_encode`:  in a PHP file I'm using this code to fetch data and to convert them into JSON format:

```
$query=$mysqli->query("SELECT nickname, count(nickname) as np FROM rating limit 10");
$rows = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
$rows[] = $row; }
$rowsjson = json_encode($rows, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); 
echo $rowsjson;
// I'm using "numeric_check" option to avoid numbers to be formatted as strings
```

2) Getting data from the external file through `$.get`:

```
<script src="inc/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$.get("test.php", function(ris) {
var result = JSON.parse(ris); 

var valori_array = [];
var nick_array = [];
var dati_array = [];

for (j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
// values_array[j] = parseFloat(result[j].np); 
// first attempt (getting just numeric data): it works
data_array[j] = '["' + result[j].nicktrasf + '", ' + parseFloat(result[j].np) + ']';
// second attempt (getting the whole thing, Nicknames+Numbers array): it doesn't work
}
```

Many questions on this part:
-Is there a way I can use directly the JSON object, not having to extract single values through the loop?
-Is the object in this format `[{"nickname":"Name1","np":55},{"nickname":"Name1","np":20}]` usable to plot a pie chart which needs data in this other format: `[["Name1",55],["Name2",20]]`??

3) Plotting a pie chart using Highcharts:

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    title: {text: 'Pie Chart Test'},       
    series: 
    [{ 
    type: 'pie',
    name: "test",
    // data:  values_array // It works, It draws a pie without names 
    // data: [["Name1",55],["Name2",20]]   // Manually, it works
    // data:  result  // It doesn't work, obvoiusly
    // data:  ris  // It doesn't work, obvoiusly
    // data:  [data_array]     // It doesn't work
    data:  data_array  // It doesn't work... why?
    }] });
```

Where am I wrong? I think I tried nearly all the possibilities with no success; the array `data_array`seems to be in the right format when I echo it (and if I try to manually cut&paste into my code the browser echo of the array, it works correctly...).
Maybe I need to convert my array into a string or something like this?
Hope someone could point my mistakes and show me the right way...

Comment: I also tried this:
`var data_test = "[" + data_array + "]";`
but it's not working too. data_test is a string with the EXACT structure needed by Highcarts pie charts data... It **should** work...

Comment: It looks like that you push stirng with "data_array" into array in php. which is incorrect. You need to have validate array of points / objects (I mean structure), which will be validate json.

Answer (score 0):

Objects and Arrays are very closely related in JavaScript, but Highcharts needs an array to process for the plotting/visualisation process

Could you try to show us the output of

`<?php var_dump($data_array); ?>`?

Comment: Mmm... There is no php variable `$data_array`... When I alert the js variable `data_array`, instead, this is the result: `["Name0", 55],["Name1", 50],["Name2", 22]` etc...

Comment: excuse me, I meant rowsjson, but it seems like that one is just missing the outer []

Comment: $rowsjson is in the format `[{"nickname":"Name0","np":55},{"nickname":"Name1","np":50}]`